# How to add spaces between numbers with Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, formatting

How can I format string "2000000.00" into  "2 000 000.00" with Kotlin?

Comment: If possible, consider using a [thin space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thin_space) (`\u2009`) rather than a normal space to separate thousands. (That seems to be the standard, according to ISO, the AMA, BIPM, IIUPAC, etc — see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_separator#Digit_grouping).) Of course, it'll look the same in monospaced fonts, but will look better elsewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with `DecimalFormat()`:

```
val dec = DecimalFormat(<pattern> [, <optional, but recommended locale>])
```

and then replace `,` with  :

```
    val number = 2000000.00
    val dec = DecimalFormat("###,###,###,###,###.00", DecimalFormatSymbols(Locale.ENGLISH))

    val formattedNumber = dec.format(number).replace(",", " ")
    println(formattedNumber)
```

`.00` is needed to keep the digits!!!

This will print:

```
2 000 000.00
```

here as a test:

```
@Test
fun testDecimalFormat() {
    val number = 2000000.00
    val dec = DecimalFormat("###,###,###,###,###.00", DecimalFormatSymbols(Locale.ENGLISH))

    val formattedNumber = dec.format(number).replace(",", " ")
    assertThat(formattedNumber).isEqualTo("2 000 000.00")
}

@Test
fun testDecimalFormatWithDigitValue() {
    val number = 2000000.01
    val dec = DecimalFormat("###,###,###,###,###.00", DecimalFormatSymbols(Locale.ENGLISH))

    val formattedNumber = dec.format(number).replace(",", " ")
    assertThat(formattedNumber).isEqualTo("2 000 000.01")
}
```

Link: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/decimalFormat.html